# CSS: horizontally center figure/image that is wider than the container

Tags: css, alignment

I want a CSS style for my html reports that should be nice to read: therefore body has a maximum width and is centered. I also want figures/img to be *centered relatively to the page*, when the image is *wider* than the container and when not it should also be centered.

I have tried some `translateX` stuff, and also tried the `display: contents;` option. I have failed using `position: absolute;`, because then the consecutive figures are vertically overlapping...

Example snippet below. How can I achieve the centering?

```css
body {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

figure,
div.figure {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #44c;
  padding: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

img {
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>
    Some text inside a paragraph that should not be too wide and centered in the page. bla bla bla blabla bla bla aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaa.
  </p>
  <figure>
    <img width=500px src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Seine_wide.jpg/640px-Seine_wide.jpg"></img>
  </figure>
  <p>
    Some text below.
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: why do you limit your body to 200px ?, can't you do that to some div instead of body ?

Comment: Because then, by default all elements have a max-width. It's also easier because I'm generating this html from a markdown document using Pandoc. I had an alternate solution where I had to style _every_ other element than `<figure>`... not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

note: you need to change max-width on .cont to make the center container grow bigger or smaller

```css
body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 text-align:center;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.cont{
 text-align:center;
 display: inline-block;
 max-width:600px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
figure{
 display: inline-block;
 margin:0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
img{
 max-width:100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
p{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align:left;
 padding:10px 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
 <figure>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Seine_wide.jpg/640px-Seine_wide.jpg" alt="">
 </figure>
 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sed vehicula erat. Proin odio nisi, fermentum ut nisi eu, laoreet rutrum leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet malesuada arcu. Cras ullamcorper enim justo, sed mattis velit ullamcorper a. Morbi ac egestas lectus. Ut sit amet maximus mauris, eget vehicula ligula. Phasellus sit amet odio gravida, tempus ipsum at, blandit odio. Morbi quis libero non metus ornare varius nec sed tellus. Aenean lacinia, dui vehicula ultrices scelerisque, ex odio viverra nunc, eget posuere tortor est faucibus dui. Aliquam vestibulum libero a auctor ultricies. Morbi sed eros odio. Phasellus molestie sit amet nisl at fermentum. Praesent est erat, tincidunt ut diam nec, molestie varius est. Duis purus libero, placerat sit amet nulla et, pharetra lobortis neque. Quisque quis risus ultricies, semper tellus sit amet, feugiat orci.
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get it, in the output the text is as wide as the figure. I would like to have text and anything else other than figure (okay, maybe not table) having a limited width. Also here, what's the difference with directly having the class `.cont` in the figure element?

Comment: In my css, is it possible to replace `body { }` with something like: `body > * { }  figure { }` (everything in body, then restyle figure) ?

Comment: lests see, do you want 2 kinds of containers?, one limited and one full with?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a concise CSS syntax for limiting the width of everything in `<body>` except `<figure>`, using the power of asterisks:

1. style all *descendants* of body but *not* body itself: `body * {max-width: 200px;}`
2. override max-width in figure only: `figure {max-width: none !important;}`
3. Make img inherit the max-width from the containing figure: `img {max-width: inherit;}`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
body * {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

figure {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #44c;
  padding: 2px;
  max-width: none !important;
}

img {
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 2px;
  max-width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>
    Some text inside a paragraph that should not be too wide and centered in the page. bla bla bla blabla bla bla aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaa.
  </p>
  <figure>
    <img width=500px src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Seine_wide.jpg/640px-Seine_wide.jpg"></img>
  </figure>
  <p>
    Some text below.
  </p>
</body>
```